# Is this possible? The intersection between a string and a set in Java.

Tags: java, string

For instance, I have a string which contains city names and a set which also contains city names.

```
String line = "I love New York, but I left my heart in San Fransisco.";
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.add("New York");
set.add("San Fransisco");
set.add("Atlanta");
```

I want to find and retrieve all the city names within the string which are also in the set. I tried using a complicated double for-loop. It works, but it doesn't seem efficient. Is there a better way?

```
for(String city1 : set){
    if (set.contains(city1)){
        for(String city2 : set){
            if(set.contains(city2) && !city1.equals(city2)){
                //inefficiently found two cities!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You meant `line.contains`?

Comment: It seems you need to find all city *pairs*?

Comment: @user7 Not necessarily all pairs. It may need to be one, two, or more cities.

Comment: `if (set.contains(city1) {...}` is completely unnecessary.  The surrounding `for` loop sets `city1` to members of `set`, so `city1` only ever contains members of `set` and  thus `set.contains(city1)` will **always** be `true`.  It doesn't affect the result, however, just adds inefficiency.

Comment: redix trie would be good  option

Comment: Then wouldn't this do `for(String city : set) if (line.contains(city)) ...`

Comment: Jorvon unless you explicitly need to optimize (Is this some big data project, where you want to be able to extract all city names from all tweets in real time in order to localize them?) It's bound to be overkill given your example. The example linked in the comments will work, but it just means that the looping is now done by the streams instead.

That said, it is more functional and readable then the loops.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using java 8 you can use like this to find all the city names containing in the set

```
String line = "I love New York, but I left my heart in San Fransisco.";
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add("New York");
set.add("San Fransisco");
set.add("Atlanta");
set.stream().filter(line::contains).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the approaches (OP's question and @janith1024's answer) are same in time complexity- `O(n*m)`; `n` is the size of the set and `m` is the number of characters in the string.

Which of the 2 approaches is *better* is a matter of preference (based on which one you feel is easier to read).

One way to get a better answer would be to be sort both the sets and compare them linearly. Then, the time complexity would be `O(n log n)` where `n` would be the size of the larger set. But the problem is, there is no way to break up the `line` into a set. You cannot break it up as words as some cities will comprise of 2 words.